# Submit form from within input radio button event using setTimout

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I need to submit a 'form' when an input radio button in the form is clicked.

If I directly call the submit from the callback, then the new radio button value is not registered and the submit sends down the old radio button value.

To make sure that the new radio checkbox value is registered in the input field, I am doing a 'setTimeout' from within the event callback per below.

```
radioButtonClick (event) {

   // do work...

    window.setTimeout(
            function () { 
                $('#submitBtn').trigger( "click");
            }, 10 
        );  

    return true;
}
```

This works and the new value for the radio is registered on the input element and seen in the form post fields.

The time out value of '10' milliseconds works on all browsers except for IE, which only works with a higher value of the timeout - something like 2000 milliseconds seems to work (even 1000 milliseconds does not seem to work most of the times). I am using IE10 for this test.

I am under the impression that as long as we return from the callback, jquery in the browser will register the new value in the input element so the timeout argument is not of material (even the value of 1 millisecond has worked on chrome and ff).

I am clearly missing something and any help is highly appreciated. Also if somebody has a better idea on how to ensure that the radio button value is persisted in the input element before calling submit (instead of using the setTimeout), then that is also highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried binding to the `change()` event rather than `click()`?  Here's a simple fiddle showing how: http://jsfiddle.net/codingsolver/MsYqx/

Comment: I am using jquery-ui buttonset() and had tried using change on that and it wasn't getting fired due to some reason. A bind to the radio's directly were causing the evening to fire twice (uncheck and check). I will set it on the input directly. I recognize that binding to change will be called after the input value has been registered in the dom, avoiding the need for setTimout ! - Many thanks David !

Comment: I also realized that I am using images on my label within the jquery-ui button set. So on IE the change event does not fire if you click on the image, but works on other browsers. That is why I had to setup a 'click' event on the label directly.

Comment: Here is the how label with images dont work on IE but on other browsers : http://jsfiddle.net/c8uywnpa/9/ which is forcing me to use the 'click' event on labels which seem to fire consistently across all browsers. If somebody can show me how get the image clicks to fire on IE, then that would be great.

Comment: I have added another question to resolve to try and fix the original issue with clicks on 'Image' within buttonset not firing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081913/jquery-change-event-not-firing-when-clicking-on-images-in-label