# jquery 'change' event not firing on Image-click for buttonset in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

Here is an example : http://jsfiddle.net/c8uywnpa/21/ which works on other browsers but IE (10).
The issue comes when a the buttonset is wrapped within a 'form' element. Please see example included.

```
<b> Form - Click on image does not work, must click on number </b>
<form>
<div id="myRadio">
    <input id="rf1" type="radio" name="myRadio" value="1" />
    <label for="rf1">1 <img src="//jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" width="50"/> </label>
    <input id="rf2" type="radio" name="myRadio" value="2" /> 
    <label for="rf2">2 <img src="//jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" width="50"/> </label>
</div>
</form>
<hr>
<h3> No Form - Click on image works </h3>
<div id="myRadioNoForm">
    <input id="r1" type="radio" name="myRadioNoForm" value="1" />
    <label for="r1">1 <img src="//jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" width="50"/> </label>
    <input id="r2" type="radio" name="myRadioNoForm" value="2" /> 
    <label for="r2">2 <img src="//jsfiddle.net/img/initializing.png" width="50"/> </label>
</div>

$("#myRadio").buttonset().on('change', function(event) {
    alert($(this).find(":checked").val()); 
});
$("#myRadioNoForm").buttonset().on('change', function(event) {
    alert($(this).find(":checked").val()); 
});
```

Clicking on the numbers in the label fires the change event but does not if you click on the Image in the label. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: for labels you need to use click event not change event.

Comment: works fine for me in IE9, 10 and 11

Comment: IE 10. (it is not an issue with click or change, it is when buttonset is wrapped within form) - strange...

Comment: Where that buttonset() is defined? If it is from jQueryUI then jQueryUI has to be included in your sample.

Comment: Here is the jsFiddle reproduction of the problem : jsfiddle.net/c8uywnpa/21 - it has all includes. Please let me know if this does not work for and I will embellish my question with the '<head>' elements. Thanks ! –

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I'm not using jQuery. I had the image wrapped with the span, so I tried to add an :after pseudoelement to it. It covers the image, so when clicking, you click on the pseudoelement rather than on the image. And it helped for me. ie9-11

```
.image { position: relative; display: block;}
.image:after {content:""; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}


<label for="answ">
    <span class="image"><img src="image.jpg"></span>
</label>
```